# How to insert a node into the tail of a linked list?

Tags: c, list, function, linked-list

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to add to the end of a linked list. for some reason my code isnt working how its intended to work. And I'm not sure whats wrong with it.

```
CmdNode *insertCommand(CmdNode *head, CmdNode *new_CmdNode) {
  /**
   * This function inserts the node new_CmdNode *at the tail* of the linked 
   * list. (You are adding a command at the end).
   * 
   * If head == NULL, then the linked list is still empty.
   * 
   * It returns a pointer to the head of the linked list with the new node 
   * added into it.
   * 
   * TODO: Implement this function
   */
    
    // check if head == NULL // list is empty >> return null and exit function 
    
    
    //CmdNode *p = NULL;
    //p = head;
    
    CmdNode *p = NULL;
    p = head;
    
    // if head is not empty 
    if(head != NULL)
    {
        //traverse the list 
        while(p->next != NULL)
        {
            // update p to the next node 
            p = p->next;
        }
        // at the end of its iteration p will point to null > update to new_Cmdnode 
        p->next = new_CmdNode;
        // return the head of list
        
    }
    else
    {
        // if list is empty the cmdnode is head 
        head = new_CmdNode;
        return head;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Why the pointless initialization of p to NULL when you could just initialize to head?

Comment: You should be able to replace `// return the head of list` with `return head;`. Or, since both branches of the `if` have `return head;` at the end, move the `return head;` statement to the end of the function.

Comment: Also, the caller of this function needs to assign the return value to the head of list pointer, for example: `mylisthead = insertCommand(mylisthead, newnode);`.

Comment: Also, something needs to set the new node's `next` pointer to `NULL`. If the caller does not do that, you will need to do it in your `insertCommand` function: `new_CmdNode->next = NULL;`.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this statement

```
return head;
```

is not outside the if-else statement. Move it after the if-else statement.

```
if(head != NULL)
{
    //...
}
else
{
    //...
}

return head;
```

Pay attention to that initially the pointer to the head node shall be set to NULL. If it is a global variable then it is already set by the compiler to NULL. Also the data member next of the node pointed to by the pointer new_CmdNode shall be already set to NULL.

The function can look like

```
CmdNode * insertCommand( CmdNode *head, CmdNode *new_CmdNode ) 
{
    if ( head == NULL )
    {
        head = new_CmdNode;
    }
    else
    {
        CmdNode *p = head;
        
        while ( p->next ) p = p->next;

        p->next = new_CmdNode;
    }

    return head;
}
```

Also bear in mind that if you are going to add new nodes to the tail of a singly-linked list then it will be more efficient to define a two-sided singly-linjed list. That is apart from the pointer to the head node also to keep a pointer to the tail node.

Answer (score 0):

I did some rewriting. Does this work?

```
CmdNode *insertCommand(CmdNode *head, CmdNode *new_CmdNode) {
    if (head == NULL) return new_CmdNode;

    CmdNode *p;
    for (p = head; p->next != NULL; p = p->next);

    p->next = new_CmdNode;
    return head;
}
```

And also it might be worth it to just keep track of the tail and add it onto that, because this way every time you want to add an element to the list, you would have go through all elements to get to the end.